# How to check sums of all possible rectangles of array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Let us assume that we have a two dimensional array A (n X n). All elements of A are either O or 1. We also have a given integer K. Our task is to find the number of all possible "rectangles" in A, which contain elements with total sum K.

```
To give an example , if A = 
0 0 1 0 
1 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
1 0 0 1   and k=3 ,

0 0 1 0
1 0 0 1  holds the property ,

1 1 1 holds the property ,

  1 1 1 holds the property ,

0 0 
1 0 
1 1 holds the property ,

1 1
1 0  holds the property ,

    1 1
    0 1  holds the property ,

1
1
1  holds the property

1
1
1 holds the property
```

So unless I missed something, the answer should be 8 for this example.

In other words, we need to check all possible rectangles in A to see if the sum of their elements is K. Is there a way to do it faster than O(n^2 * k^2) ?

Comment: Wouldn't the naive algorithm of checking all rectangles take `O(n^4)` time?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's worse than you calculated. I found a total of 14 rectangles with three 1's (green squares). The method I used was to take each `{row,column}` position in the array as the upper-left of a rectangle, and then consider every possible combination of width and height.

Since the width and height are not constrained by `k`(at least not directly), the search time is `O(n^4)`. Of course, for any given `{row,column,width}`, the search ends when the height is such that the sum is greater than `k`. But that doesn't change the worst case time.

The three starting points in the lower-right need not be considered because it's not possible to construct a rectangle containing `k` 1's starting from those positions. But again, that doesn't change the time complexity.

<sub>Note: I'm aware that this is more of a comment than an answer. However, it doesn't fit in a comment, and I believe it's still useful to the OP. You can't solve a problem until you fully understand it.</sub>

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could do this in O(n^3).

First note that a [summed area table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table) allows you to compute the sum of any rectangle in O(1) time given O(n^2) preprocessing time.

In this problem we only need to sum the columns, but the general technique is worth knowing.

Then for each start row and end row combination you can do a linear scan across the matrix to count the solutions either with a two pointers approach or simply by storing the previous sums.

Example Python code (finds 14 solutions to your example):

```py
from collections import defaultdict
A=[[0, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 1]]
k=3

h=len(A)
w=len(A[0])

C=[ [0]*w for i in range(h+1)]
for x in range(w):
    for y in range(1,h+1):
        C[y][x] = C[y-1][x] + A[y-1][x]
# C[y][x] contains sum of all values A[y2][x] with y2<y

count=0
for start_row in range(h):
    for end_row in range(start_row,h):
        D=defaultdict(int) # Key is sum of columns from start to here, value is count
        D[0]=1
        t=0 # Sum of all A[y][x] for x <= col, start_row<=y<=end_row
        for x in range(w):
            t+=C[end_row+1][x] - C[start_row][x]
            count += D[t-k]
            D[t] += 1
print count
```