# Given a square, binary matrix, calculate number of submatrices with a particular sum

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix

Suppose we are given a NxN square and binary matrix and a positive number K. We need to find the number of submatrices, so that the sum of values of each submatrix is equal to K. I have tried using the idea of a Summed Area Table as it was explained here: [Calculate the sum of elements in a matrix efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277749/calculate-the-sum-of-elements-in-a-matrix-efficiently)

and here: [Calculate the sum of elements in a matrix efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277749/calculate-the-sum-of-elements-in-a-matrix-efficiently)

but my best solution has an O(n^4) complexity as i need to examine every possible submatrix and not just one submatrix as on the links above. Any help would be really appreciated.

Edit: Sorry for not clearing that up. So if the input matrix is 3x3 {001}{010}{000} and K=1, the output should be 17, which means we have found every possible submatrix that the sum of its values is equal to K. For input:
        {0, 1, 0, 1, 0} 
        {1, 0, 1, 0, 1} 
        {0, 1, 0, 1, 0} 
        {1, 0, 1, 0, 1} 
        {0, 1, 0, 1, 0} and K=6, the expected outcome is 12. Here is my code, suppose we have already constructed the Summed Area Table (satMatrix)

```
 count=0;

for(i=0; i<N; i++)                    //main loop
{
    for(j=0; j<N; j++)
    {           
        sumOfSubmatrix=satMatrix[i][j];
        if(sumOfSubmatrix==K) count++ ;

        for(int i1=0; i1<i; i1++)
        {
            sumOfSubmatrix=satMatrix[i][j]-satMatrix[i1][j];
            if(sumOfSubmatrix==K) count++ ;
        }

        for(int j1=0; j1<j; j1++)
        {
            sumOfSubmatrix=satMatrix[i][j]-satMatrix[i][j1];
            if(sumOfSubmatrix==K) count++ ;
        }

    }    

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  In general, you should include your best effort at a solution in your question. It helps us gauge the level at which you're working.  It also shows that you have tried — though it should be an MCVE ([MCVE]).  For example, you could encode the example matrix as an initialized array.  You should give sample input and expected vs actual output.  If the O(N^4) code is working, it may even belong on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than SO. Are the sub-matrices square too? Are the numbers positive?

Comment: Isn't that trivially `sum of matrix / K`?

Comment: @NicoSchertler: No — or, at least, why would it be?  The objective is to find a (contiguous) subset of the cells in the given array such that the elements sum to K (where the cells and K are probably all integers, though the question doesn't say that).  And that sort of calculation is not as simple as 'sum of matrix / K'.

Comment: I may have misinterpreted the question. So you are not looking for a partitioning of the matrix (i.e. every cell belongs to exactly one submatrix). In that case, the above formula would hold. But I see that this might not be the case here. I assume you are looking for the maximum number of submatrices, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check sums of all possible rectangles of array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321927/how-to-check-sums-of-all-possible-rectangles-of-array)

Comment: @NicoSchertler exactly. You are right,that is what i'm looking for. I did not make it clear from the beginning .